# Calculate weighted usage of an item

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheets workbook with 2 worksheets.

Sheet 1 lists about 1000 items (components). The list could grow.
[image]
(ignore E through K columns in the above example)

Sheet 2 lists some products (200 or so at the moment, but the list could grow). Each product could contain up to 12 components. These are listed in columns C through N (all of these columns have data validation so that these need to be selected from Sheet 1's list of 1000 components). Column R contains the number of units of the product.
[image]

On sheet 1, next to each component, I want to calculate the number of units of the component used across all products. Of course `countif` will count only the instances of the particular component in `Sheet 1!C2:N200`. Similarly `sumproduct` doesn't fit the bill because 1. C through N are not numerical and 2. C through N are not fixed.

Is there a simple way to calculate the number of units for each component?
(without using VBScript/Javascript, and without copy-pasting the transpose list of components onto Sheet 2)

I am thinking some quirky way of using `sumif` or `sumifs` may be the answer here, but haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Why does `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!C:N=A1))` not work? `A1` being the obvious placeholder for your cell on the 1st sheet.

Comment: @JvdV Not sure I understand the formula. Just to clarify what I need: I need the formula to check all rows for cols C to N for the component (A1 in your example) and if component is found for the row then add the value stated in R to the sum and do this for all rows in which the A1 value is found.

Comment: can you share a simplified spreadsheet?

Comment: Right @OC2PS, so `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!C:N=A1)*Sheet2!R:R)` is better? Anyway, you have an answer I see =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sheet1 cell B2. put this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet2!C2:N&"|"&Sheet2!R2:R),"|",0,0),"select Col1,SUM(Col2) group by Col1"),2,0)))
```

if you want to return 0s instead of blanks for unused components, this slight modification should do it.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet2!C2:N&"|"&Sheet2!R2:R),"|",0,0),"select Col1,SUM(Col2) group by Col1"),2,0),0)))
```

[Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lokoms22tuqU53TlhAcdqaldQe_H7Pq8Jah2kBBYo7c/edit)

Comment: @OC2PS based on your reputation, I assume you know how to translate if you're in a European locale that uses ; instead of , for parameter separators...

Comment: Note also that this formula is meant to act on the entirety of column B in Sheet1.  You would need to delete any other formulas that were below cell B2, and therefore "in the way" of the output of this formula.

Comment: That worked! You are awesome. However, I am not familiar with Array Formulas. For me, and for others arriving at this page, would you mind expanding your answer by explaining the components of the formula and what's going on? P.S. I am using the second version of your formula, with a few small adjustments relevant for my sheet, e.g. cell addresses etc.

Comment: @OC2PS sure thing.  here's a sample sheet created specifically for this problem.  I have laid out most of the steps on the tab called MK.Demo.  Hope that helps!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lokoms22tuqU53TlhAcdqaldQe_H7Pq8Jah2kBBYo7c/edit

Comment: @MattKing, I appreciate having the spreadsheet demo, instead of one from OC2PS!

Answer (score 0):

A complementary way is to build a data base

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet2!A2:A&"|"&Sheet2!C2:N&"|"&Sheet2!R2:R),"|",,false))
```

and then compute via a pivot table, added in
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lokoms22tuqU53TlhAcdqaldQe_H7Pq8Jah2kBBYo7c/edit#gid=1233865099

[image]